# Multiple Choice Quiz - not updating responses

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form that outputs:

1. Quiz_Assign_ID (Combines User_ID with Quiz ID)
2. Question ID
3. Checkboxes for inputting the response (Option A, Option B, Option C)

```html
<div class="Main">
  
  <form method="post" action="LP_Quiz_Student_Quiz_Responses.php">

<?php
$quiz_id = trim($_GET['quiz_id']);
$quiz_assign_id = trim($_GET['quiz_assign_id']);

$i = 1;

$count=1;



$sel_query=("SELECT Quiz.quiz_id, Quiz.quiz_title, Quiz_Questions.quiz_id, Quiz_Questions.quiz_question_id, Quiz_Questions.question, Quiz_Questions.option1, Quiz_Questions.option2, Quiz_Questions.option3, Quiz_Questions.answer FROM Quiz, Quiz_Questions WHERE (Quiz.quiz_id=Quiz_Questions.quiz_id) and (Quiz.quiz_id=?)");

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sel_query); 

$stmt->bind_param("i", $quiz_id);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
 
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No Quiz Questions!');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  ?>



      <p></p>



    
<p>&nbsp;</p>

  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
          <td>
          <input name="quiz_assign_id" type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $quiz_assign_id; ?>" />&nbsp;<input name="quiz_question_id" type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $row["quiz_question_id"]; ?>" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <h4>Question <?php echo $i++; ?>  </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
          <h4><?php echo $row["question"]; ?>&nbsp;</h4>
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <h4>A</h4>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $row["option1"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
        
              <input name="Response[<?php echo $quiz_question_id; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="Option A" style="width: 20px" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <h4>B</h4>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $row["option2"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
        
              <input name="Response[<?php echo $quiz_question_id; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="Option B" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <h4>C</h4>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo $row["option3"]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
        
              <input name="Response[<?php echo $quiz_question_id; ?>]" type="checkbox" value="Option C" /></td>
      </tr>
 
 
  
   </table>


   <?php
  
  
  }
  
  ?>
 <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form> 

</div>
```

Upon submission I run the following script, which captures the response but does not get the question_id and Quiz_Assign_ID and does not update the values in the database:

```
<?php
    


    
    if(!empty($_POST['Response'])) {
    
        foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $value) {



    $quiz_assign_id=trim($_POST['quiz_assign_id']); 
    $quiz_question_id=$_POST['quiz_question_id'];   
    
    
echo 'Answer'; echo $value;
 echo 'Question:';  echo $quiz_question_id;
 echo 'Student ID';  echo $quiz_assign_id; echo 'successfully assigned! <br>';


    
    
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare('UPDATE Quiz_Assign_Student_Question SET response = ? WHERE quiz_assign_id = ? and quiz_question_id =? ');
    
    
    if (
        $stmt &&
        $stmt -> bind_param('sss', $value, $quiz_assign_id, $quiz_question_id) &&
        $stmt -> execute() &&
        $stmt -> affected_rows === 1
    ) {
        echo "<script>
         alert('Responses submitted!'); 
         window.history.go(-2);
         </script>";
        
        
    } else {
        echo"<script>
         window.history.go(-2);
         </script>";

    }
    }
    }
    
    
    
    ?>
```

I have been playing with it for hours, but with no luck.

Comment: Could you share the code that fills the `$row["quiz_question_id"]` of the hidden inputs?

Comment: @Daantje silly me, I had not added the field in the query Duh - thanks
The next issue is, I am only getting the response of the last question and not of each one. There are three Qs but it only records the response of the last one?

Comment: I see only one question in your form. I see an `}`, did you forgot to share the `for` loop code?

Comment: Each $row outputs a question and three options for each one

Comment: Use `name="Response[".$row["quiz_assign_id"]."][]"`, so you can find the answer, or else they are all in one array.

Comment: If you still have problems, please share the whole form code, with the for loop. Check if the form tag is outside your for loop first.

Comment: @Daantje I have posted the complete code now, I tried what you suggested but still assigns the checkbox value to the last question (question 1 of 3) rather than all.

Comment: I've added an answer that explains how to work with radio and check boxes. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using check boxes en not radio buttons, you should change your input checkbox name attribute, so it's sending a nested array with the question ID as a key and the answers array as the value, like so: *(notice the extra `[]`)* Also `$quiz_question_id` is not defined, you should use the `$row` array.

```php
<input name="Response[<?php echo $row['quiz_question_id']; ?>][]" type="checkbox" value="Option A" style="width: 20px" /></td>
```

Because the response array is now nested, the question answers are grouped by question_id. To iterate over the nested response array, use the following for loop:

```php
foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $question_id => $answered) {
    echo "Question ID:".$question_id."<br />";

    // iterate answers
    foreach ($answered as $answer) {
        echo "Answered: ".$answer."<br />";
    }

    // Or transform to comma separated string
    echo "Answered: ".implode(", ", $answered)."<br />";
}
```

So your **LP_Quiz_Student_Quiz_Responses.php** could look like this:

```php
if(!empty($_POST['Response'])) {
    $done = 0;

    foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $quiz_question_id => $values) {
        $quiz_assign_id = trim($_POST['quiz_assign_id']); 
        
        echo 'Answers'; print_r($values); // Values is an array here.
        echo 'Question:';  echo $quiz_question_id;
        echo 'Student ID';  echo $quiz_assign_id; echo 'successfully assigned! <br>';
        
        // Because $values is an array, transform it into a comma separated string to insert them into the database
        // But you could also make a database table with answers and loop over the $values array.
        $value = implode(', ', $values);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Quiz_Assign_Student_Question SET response = ? WHERE quiz_assign_id = ? and quiz_question_id =? ');
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $value, $quiz_assign_id, $quiz_question_id); 
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $done++;
        }
    }

    echo "<script>";
    if ($done) {
        echo "alert('Responses submitted!');";
    } 
    echo "window.history.go(-2);";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

To accommodate both type of questions with check boxes and questions with radio buttons, you can use the same response code, but first check if its an array before transforming it into a string.

**Questions with radio buttons,** *one answer per question possible:*

```php
<input name="Response[<?php echo $row['quiz_question_id']; ?>]" type="radio" value="Option A" style="width: 20px" /></td>
```

**Questions with check boxes,** *multiple answers per question possible:*

```php
<input name="Response[<?php echo $row['quiz_question_id']; ?>][]" type="checkbox" value="Option A" style="width: 20px" /></td>
```

And now your **LP_Quiz_Student_Quiz_Responses.php** could look like this:

```php
if(!empty($_POST['Response'])) {
    $done = 0;

    foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $quiz_question_id => $values) {
        $quiz_assign_id = trim($_POST['quiz_assign_id']); 
        
        // If it's an array (checkbox), transform to string. 
        // Else it is already a string (radio).
        if (is_array($values)) {        
            $values = implode(', ', $values);
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Quiz_Assign_Student_Question SET response = ? WHERE quiz_assign_id = ? and quiz_question_id =? ');
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $values, $quiz_assign_id, $quiz_question_id); 
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $done++;
        }
    }

    echo "<script>";
    if ($done) {
        echo "alert('".$done." Responses submitted!');";
    } 
    echo "window.history.go(-2);";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

But with above code you can accommodate all kind of field types.

To put it simple:

```php
foreach ($_POST['Response'] as $question_id => $answered) {
    echo "Question ID:".$question_id."<br />";

    // Check if array, it's a checkbox or multiple select question
    if (is_array($answered)) {
        // iterate answers
        foreach ($answered as $answer) {
            echo "Answered: ".$answer."<br />";
        }

        // Or transform to comma separated string
        echo "Answered: ".implode(", ", $answered)."<br />";
    } else {
        // radio, hidden, input, select or textarea question
        echo "Answered: ".$answered."<br />";    
    }
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.